# Setting up a custom domain on LAN

Tags: dns, lan

I would like to access my main PC as `<some-name>.local` (or just generally with a domain name) from other devices on the same LAN. From what I've read so far, it seems that I would have to run a DNS server which is far too much trouble for this minor QoL improvement.

However, I have noticed that the VLC player app on my iPad can setup a webserver for me to upload files over to the iPad through a browser. That uploader is accessed as `<my-ipad-name>.local` and it works out of the box, without requiring me to do any prior setup (like editing hosts) on the machine I'm accessing the URL from.

How is this possible, and can I do the same for my PC?

Answer (score 0):

To do the same on your pc, simply modify the hosts file.
You will need to add every host name of the devices in your lan with the associated IP. [here's a link showing how to do that](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/helpdeskgeek.com/networking/edit-hosts-file/amp/)

Now one important point is that this dns entry is not "propagated" from your iPad or any device to the other ones.
So if your iPad calls himself "ipad1.local" your windows pc won't know this and you will need to add this specific entry to the hosts file.

Comment: See, this is the thing. Somehow my PC does know - the iPad calls itself `<my-ipad-name>.local` and it works on my PC without modifying the hosts file or any other prior setup.